# Probability - Is my answer ok?

Tags: probability

Each item in a computer parts catalogue is given a unique code consisting of two distinct
uppercase letters followed by four distinct digits. For example, the code for a particular
keyboard is XY1702.

a. How many different item codes are available (keeping in mind that repetition of
letters and digits is not permitted)

ANS

```
26 X 25 X 10 X 9 X 8 X 7 = 3276000
```

b. Suppose a sales clerk wants to order a particular item, and knows that the item code
begins with the letters DE, and that the digits 8 and 6 occur in the code. How many
different item codes meet this description?

ANS

```
8 X 7 = 56
```

c. If the sales clerk knows that the item code begins with the letters DE and that the
digits 8 and 6 occur in the code, what is the probability that she guesses the code
correctly on her first guess?

ANS

```
 1/56 = 0.017
```

Is my answer correct? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part (a) is good. The problem with the other two parts is that we don't know **where** the digits $8$ and $6$ occur in the code or in what **order** they appear in. Note that there are $4$ ways to select the digit slot for placing the $8$. This leaves $3$ ways to select the digit slot for placing the $6$. At this point, there are eight remaining digits that need to fill up two slots. The third slot can be filled in $8$ ways, which leaves $7$ ways to fill the last slot.

Hence, we obtain $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 = 672$ ways for part (b) and $1/672$ for part (c).

Comment: Wow. Your explanation made so much sense. Thank you. God Bless you!

Comment: No problem, glad I can help. =]